# Best way to register resource hierarchy?

Tags: jetty

I want to use Jetty to register servlets or filters to handle the following REST endpoints:

- class UsersResource: `/api/v1/users`
- class UserResource : `/api/v1/users/{userId}`
- class OrdersResource : `/api/v1/users/{userId}/orders`
- class OrderResource : `/api/v1/users/{userId}/orders/{orderId}`

and serve static resources at `/static/*`.

Coming from a JAX-RS world, I am used to registering a top-level filter to handle `/*` and have it delegate calls to sub-resources as needed. Meaning, Jetty was only aware of the top-level filter. This has the negative side-effect of handling static resources through JAX-RS.

On the other hand, I don't think that Jetty can handle all requests because servlet/filter pathSpecs are very primitive. They do not accept regular expressions so I am forced to match paths that the underlying resource does not want to handle.

What is the appropriate way to represent this hierarchy in Jetty without the use JAX-RS?

1. Are servlets or filters more appropriate for this case? Or it doesn't matter?
2. Would you register a separate servlet/filter for each resource, or one top-level servlet/filter that delegates to sub-resources?
3. Specifically, what kind of pathSpec would one register for `/api/v1/users/{id}`?

For reference, here is how I've implemented this to date: [Hot Deployment of servlet contexts loaded from classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57294096/14731)

Comment: Are you using embedded-jetty? or standalone with a webapp/war file?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Embedded jetty. See the link at the end of the question for an example of what my code looks like now.