# Hot Deployment of servlet contexts loaded from classpath?

Tags: java, jetty, hotswap

I've got the following embedded Jetty setup:

```
    ServletContextHandler topHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server, contextPath);

    // Set path of static resources
    topHandler.setBaseResource(...);

    // Bind dynamic content to /api
    RootResource rootResource = new RootResource();
    FilterHolder restApiHandler = new FilterHolder(rootResource);
    for (Entry<String, String> parameter : initParams.entrySet())
        restApiHandler.setInitParameter(parameter.getKey(), parameter.getValue());
    topHandler.addFilter(restApiHandler, "/api/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));

    // Bind static content to /
    ServletHolder staticResourceHandler = topHandler.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");

    server.start();
```

And I found documentation on Hot Deployment at https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.19.v20190610/hot-deployment.html but I don't understand how to put these together.

How do I get Jetty to reload servlets after their class files are reloaded so I don't have to restart the server every time I modify a Java file during development?

Answer (score 0):

Hot Deployment is typically a feature of a `WebAppContext` and the WAR concept that provides isolated ClassLoaders.

The `ServletContextHandler` would need a custom ClassLoader to mimic the isolated classloader behaviors that the `WebAppContext` provides.

Hot Deployment is a feature of the `DeploymentManager` and an associated `AppProvider` that does the scanning to detect changes (like on a file system).

You'll want a `DeploymentManager` as a bean on your `Server`.

And you'll want to select a `AppProvider` (such as `WebAppProvider`) to monitor a directory for changes and trigger new App updates back to the `DeploymentManager`.

Next, you'll want to have your `ServletContextHandler` declared entirely in the XML deployable format in that monitored directory.

The classes you are modifying need to come from somewhere that ISN'T part of the Server ClassLoader.

The XML deployable you are using will need to create this isolated custom classloader and load the classes from this new (non-server) location.

These combined are what you are looking at for Hot Deployment.

Comment: Do you have any sample code that does Hot Deployment for a `WebAppContext`? I see https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/DeployWebApps.java and https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/WebAppContextFromClasspath.java but it's not clear how to link them together.

Also, does the `ServletContextHandler` have to be declared in XML deployable format if I don't need to redeploy when its configuration changes? I only need to redeploy if the servlets change.